# How to find the user is start responding or not at the other end via server?[ i.e.In edittext they typing or not]

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery

In my application I need to do the functionality ( is typing...) concept. Like in WhatsApp , if user is start responding to the other user it shows the user is typing..

Likewise I need to find the user at the other end starts responding or not. In whatsapp app they may use some advance socket concept XMPP something. I want to do with simple php call. Is there possibility to do Using broadcast reciever and normal API call or suggest me some solution . 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `TextChangedListener` like this way :

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

            // send a request like user is typing to your server and in your server pass this request to your other user

            }
    });
```